# jQuery execute if variable contains string

Tags: jquery, ajax, if-statement, click

Alright, so I have a button that when clicked, will change the class of a given div. The thing is, I only want this to happen if a variable (answer) does not contain the string "No". This works... but the problem is that even if the variable doesn't contain the word "No", the code won't execute. The ajax result contains either "No User ID" or "User ID:#".

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.like').on('click', function() {
    postID = $(this).attr('id').replace('like_', '');

    // Declare variables
    value = '1';

    myajax();

    return false;

    var doit = answer.IndexOf("No");
    if (doit < 0){
        $('#post_' + postID).removeClass('dislike').addClass('like');
    }

});

function myajax(){
    // Send values to database
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check.php',
        //check.php receives the values sent to it and stores them in the database
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'postID=' + postID + '&value=' + value,
        success: function(result) {
            answer = result;
            $('#Message_' + postID).html('').html(result).prependTo('#post_' + postID);
        }
    });
}
});
```

SO I know my problem lies with the var doit. I just can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `success` function is executing after the call to `myajax` returns

the first 'a' in ajax stands for asynchronous, so you want to move the entire block of code into the success function, likeso:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.like').on('click', function() {
    postID = $(this).attr('id').replace('like_', '');

    // Declare variables
    value = '1';

    myajax(function(answer) {
           if (answer.indexOf("No") < 0){
              $('#post_' + postID).removeClass('dislike').addClass('like');
            }
    });

    return false;

});

   $('.dontlike').click(function() {
     myajax(function(answer) { alert('check.php returned:' + answer); }
   });

function myajax(onSuccess){
    // Send values to database
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check.php',
        //check.php receives the values sent to it and stores them in the database
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'postID=' + postID + '&value=' + value,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#Message_' + postID).html('').html(result).prependTo('#post_' + postID);
            onSuccess(result);
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Though maybe `var answer = result;` would be better? Or just `result.indexOf("No")`? Also I think it's a lowercase `i` in `indexOf`.

Comment: This solution will not work. the ajax exists in a function for a reason. I have another button (dislike) which also executes the same function but sets the variables differently. If I put indexOf inside my ajax, it will not make the distinction between which button was clicked.